# How to delete all releases and tags in a github repository

Tags: git, github, github-cli, github-release

I tried the github cli:

```
gh release list | sed 's/|/ /' | awk '{print $1, $8}' | while read -r line; do gh release delete -y "$line"; done
```

as described here: https://dev.to/dakdevs/delete-all-releases-from-github-repo-13ad

But it only works for releases where the name equals the tag. As soon as a name has spaces in it, awk fails to separate the columns properly.

maybe the `gh` cli output changed since the article was written or `awk` on macos has different defaults?

Answer (score 7):

Adding `-F '\t'` helped `awk` to separate the columns correctly. This command deletes all gh releases:

```
gh release list | awk -F '\t' '{print $3}' | while read -r line; do gh release delete -y "$line"; done
```

You can also delete the tags with the following flag:

```
--cleanup-tag   Delete the specified tag in addition to its release
```

Answer (score 1):

I happened to need to do this exact thing (delete all of the releases in a repo), and I was able to use `cut` for this successfully. Here's the command I ran:

```bash
gh release list --limit 500 \
  | cut -f3 \
  | while read release_tag; do
  gh release delete -y "$release_tag"
done
```

This works because the `gh` output is tab-separated, and `cut` separates fields by tabs by default. So `cut -f3` takes the third field in the output, which is the release tag.

Other notes:

- The `-y` option makes it so that it doesn't ask you to confirm before deleting each release. Useful if you're confident that you know what you're doing and you have a lot of releases to delete.
- The `--limit 500` part is optional. The default page size is 30, so if you have more than 30 releases, you need to use the `--limit` option to make the page size bigger and fetch *all* of your releases, instead of just the first 30.
- [Like Jonas mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75237632/2338327), you can include the `--cleanup-tag` option when deleting a release to also delete the tag.